# How to select a file named by strange character in a folder which has 2 same prefix file existed in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

such as:

```
admin@DESKTOP-M6V5E4A MINGW64 ~/Workspace
$ vi file_
file_2.json            file_▒▒▒ָ▒▒▒▒ģ▒顣.json
```

[image]

I can't use my mouse,how can I select the file_▒▒▒ָ▒▒▒▒ģ▒顣.json?

I'v tried press my tab.but it just list all same-prefix file.

Comment: what do you get when you do a `echo file_*顣.json`?

Comment: I am very much a fan of the shell, but if you have access to a GUI on this machine, then running a graphical file browser on it would give you an easy way to select or rename this file.  I forget whether `gvim` offers a graphical file chooser, but that might be a way to open the file without changing its name.  Or if you're open to a different editor then there are GUI text editors that *definitely* provide graphical file choosers.

Comment: use enough question marks (single character wildcard) so you don't match on `_2`, eg, `vi file_??*.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be very elegant but it works…

```
ls file_* > script.sh
vi script.sh
```

Leave only the file you want to edit and put the `vi` command in front of the file name. The script will look like this:

```
vi file_XXXXXXX.json
```

Save and run the script…

```
chmod u+x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's just one file, you can use a negative character class:

```
vi file_[^2]*.json
```

If you need more flexibility, enable `shopt -s extglob` (see `man bash` for details). It enables extended pattern matching, e.g.

```
vi file_!(2.txt)
```

Comment: A glob pattern could work even if there's more than one file matching it.  `vi` (or `vim`, at least) supports designating multiple input files on the command line, and it offers commands for navigating among them.